# Artifactory Docker Registry Setup Issue

Tags: docker, artifactory

We recently created a docker registry in artifactory. In order to set it up properly, we had to configure a reverse proxy. Instructions here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy

After setting up the proxy, when trying to login to artifactory using the following command:

docker login

We get a 404 error. When we try to use base64 for our password, the password is not recognized.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If you have and resolved it, can you please explain how you did it?

Artifactory Version: 4.14.2
Docker Version 1.12.3

Thank you

Comment: We use jFrog's bintray product to host Docker images, and it was extremely simple to set up. Is it an option to use that?

Comment: At the moment it is not.

Comment: what does following command give?
>docker login your-artifactory-url:5001 

Also have you added insecure registry option with your artifactory_url  in  docker installation ?

Comment: It gives me "Error response from daemon: Get https://url.com:5001/v1/users/: dial tct XXX.XX.XXX.XX:5001: i/o timeout"         when passing the flag I get the following error "unknown flag: --insecure-registry"

Comment: From the error it seems the registry url (actually your reverse proxy configuration) is pointing to the wrong place.   The request should look like this `url.com:5001/artifactory/api/docker/v2`

Comment: Do you have access to Artifactory server log files - the "request.log" and "artifactory.log" files? Can you check the corresponding entries in these log files?